# Grails controller's beforeInterceptor

Tags: grails

I am trying to make it so that no matter what function of my controller is accessed, if the session has been nulled, it goes back to the log in page after you click ok on a modal that pops up saying the session has expired but I can't quite get it to work. Here are the first few methods of this controller:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
        [action:this.&checkSession()]
    }

    def checkSession() {
        if (!session.user) {
            render text: """<script type="text/javascript"> alert('Session expired. Please log in again.'); window.location.href = data.url;</script>""",
                    contentType: 'js'

        }
    }

    def index() {
        redirect (action: customerLogin)
    }

    def customerLogin = {
        selectedBatch = null
    }

    def authenticate = {

        def user = null

        def possibleUsersList = User.findAllWhere(user_name: params.username)

        possibleUsersList.each { 
            if (bcryptService.checkPassword(params.password, it.user_password))
                user = it
        }

        if (user) {
                session.user = user
                greetingName = user.user_name
                render(contentType: 'text/json') {
                        [success: true, url: createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'custMainPage')]
                }
        }
        else {
            //def messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle('messages')
            //def errorstring = bundle.getString("fatcaone.login.error")
            //println "Login error: " + ${errorstring} 
            render (contentType: 'text/json') {
                //["message": '<p>code=fatcaone.login.error</p>']
                ["message": '<p>Login or Password incorrect.</p>']
            }
        }
    }

    def logout = {
        if (session.user != null) {
            flash.message = "Goodbye ${session.user.fullName}"
            session.user = null

        }
        redirect(action: customerLogin)
    }
```

Comment: Reading through the Grails documentation I don't think you are using that correctly. http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html I don't think you can compose model/views in such a manner (e.g. calling render and continue processing).

Comment: @Joshua Moore I know I'm not doing it right but given how I have my code laid out, is it possible to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: It is possible to accomplish this, but your approach is entirely off. The best solution would be to use a filter, afterView and modify the model to contain a specific value/variable that you would then in turn check in your layout/gsp and optionally include the javascript you need.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman looking at this long time later. Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

beforeInterceptor has been removed from Grails 3.0.
See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/635 for a discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to keep your code as it is do:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    [action:this.&checkSession()]
}

private def checkSession() {
    if (!session.user) {
        flash.error = 'Session expired. Please log in again.'

        redirect(action: customerLogin)
        return false

    }
}

def index() {
    redirect (action: customerLogin)
}

def customerLogin = {
    selectedBatch = null
}

def authenticate = {

    def user = null

    def possibleUsersList = User.findAllWhere(user_name: params.username)

    possibleUsersList.each { 
        if (bcryptService.checkPassword(params.password, it.user_password))
            user = it
    }

    if (user) {
            session.user = user
            greetingName = user.user_name
            render(contentType: 'text/json') {
                    [success: true, url: createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'custMainPage')]
            }
    }
    else {
        //def messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle('messages')
        //def errorstring = bundle.getString("fatcaone.login.error")
        //println "Login error: " + ${errorstring} 
        render (contentType: 'text/json') {
            //["message": '<p>code=fatcaone.login.error</p>']
            ["message": '<p>Login or Password incorrect.</p>']
        }
    }
}

def logout = {
    if (session.user != null) {
        flash.message = "Goodbye ${session.user.fullName}"
        session.user = null

    }
    redirect(action: customerLogin)
}
```

And in your login page add:

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        alert('${flash.error}');
    </script>
</g:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
def checkSession() {
   if (session == null || session["loginId"] == null) {
        render text: """<script type="text/javascript"> alert('Session expired. Please log in again.'); window.location.href = "${createLink(controller: 'test',action: 'logout')}";</script>""",
                contentType: 'js';
        return false;
    } 
}
```